# Wordpress Jetpack Plugin - Adding Jetpack's related posts support to my theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jetpack

i read the Jetpack for developers section, but i am missing information how i can integrate the related posts feature that comes with jetpack into my own theme. Does anybody know a ressource where i can find that piece of information or has the code handy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Really you're not have to do so much to get it work in default mode.
Take a look at: http://jetpack.me/support/related-posts/

In case of you need more customization, then this maybe help you: http://jetpack.me/support/customize-related-posts/